# Google App Engine Deploy Error[12] Cannot allocate memory

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-build

My Application is running as 
  - Google App Engine Standard Environment : Python 37

I deploy my application using gcloud as following command

> gcloud app deploy --project [project-name] --version uno

my build fail as the following error

```
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     gzip_tar_runtime_package took 18 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     Finished gzipping tarfile.
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     Building app layer took 47 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: Building app layer
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: tar_runtime_package
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     tar_runtime_package tar -pcf /tmp/tmpyhSCMU.tar --hard-dereference --transform flags=r;s,^,/.googleconfig/, --exclude *.pyc .
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     tar_runtime_package took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     Building app layer took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     build process for FTL image took 50 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     full build took 50 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR    tar_runtime_package tar -pcf /tmp/tmpyhSCMU.tar --hard-dereference --transform flags=r;s,^,/.googleconfig/, --exclude *.pyc .
Step #1 - "builder": exited with error [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
Step #1 - "builder": tar_runtime_package is likely not on the path
Step #1 - "builder": Traceback (most recent call last):
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
Step #1 - "builder":     "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
Step #1 - "builder":     exec code in run_globals
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 65, in <module>
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 60, in main
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/common/ftl_error.py", line 77, in InternalErrorHandler
Step #1 - "builder": IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '""/output'
```

More Information

- My Task Queue is already empty.
- I try to up size my instance class from F1 to F2 and F3 and it still fail.

Comment: This might be related with requirements. Can you add `requirements.txt`?

Comment: The last line here looks suspect, are you specifying `""/output` somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error `cannot allocate memory` usually appears if the number of files or the size of the content that is being uploaded is too big and the instance used to deploy your code runs out of memory.

The cause of this error might be the fact that you are using too many dependencies or static files.

Are you downloading static files ? I see this command `tar_runtime_package tar` before the error.

I would suggest to make sure you only use the necessary dependencies or choose to deploy your application on Google Cloud Run.

Comment: Thank you for your advise I just try to cut some static files packed during deploy code, I can deploy my code again. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try increasing the memory allocation?

```
resources:
    disk_size_gb: 10
```

Comment: I check app.yaml configuration document and not found any where mention "resources" tag. Did it in app.yaml? or other files

Comment: in the app.yaml file

Comment: Do you have any documents related to "resources" tag?