# Deploying Google Cloud Function with Tensorflow fails

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a google cloud function to use the [universal-sentence-encoder](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4) model.

However, if I add in the dependencies to my `requirements.txt`:

```
tensorflow==2.1
tensorflow-hub==0.8.0
```

then the function fails to deploy with the following error:

```
Build failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INTERNAL", "errorMessage": "gzip_tar_runtime_package gzip /tmp/tmpOBr2rZ.tar -1\nexited with error [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory\ngzip_tar_runtime_package is likely not on the path", "errorType": "InternalError", "errorId": "F57B9E18"}}
```

What does this error mean?
How can I fix it?

Note that the code for the function itself is just the demo code provided by google when you click "create function" in the web console. It deploys when I remove these requirements, when I add them it breaks.

Comment: I think there is alredy an answer to this question, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60866354/google-app-engine-deploy-error12-cannot-allocate-memory.

Comment: thanks but that seems to be a different problem, different error and different cause

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen when the size of the deployed files is larger than the available Cloud Function memory. The gzip_tar_runtime_package could not be installed because memory could not be allocated.

Make sure you are only using the required dependencies. If you are uploading static files, make sure you only upload necessary files.

After that, if you are still facing the issue, try increasing the Cloud Function Memory setting the `--memory` flag in the `gcloud functions deploy` command as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--memory)

**EDIT:**

There is currently a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/151074055) with Tensorflow 2.1 in Cloud Functions.
The current workaround would be to use Tensorflow 2.0.0 or 2.0.1

Comment: thanks @jose-v I was already using the 2Gb memory instance. My function only has 20 lines of code. I did manage to get it to deploy by downgrading to an older tensorflow version but then it ran out of memory while trying to download my model. I'm going to find another solution to run it as this is unworkable.

Comment: Cloud Run also has a limitation of 2 GB of memory ([source](https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas#cloud_run_limits)), and App Engine's instance class with the max amount of memory has also 2 GB ([source](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard#instance_classes)). Maybe something like Compute Engine would be more suitable for your needs